# Search keyword from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I want to search some keyword from GeoServer, like "E11" or "停車場" (Chinese), 
My request is below:

EX: Search "E11" :

```
    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
    outputFormat="JSON" 
    xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"  
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"  
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"  
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
    http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Query typeName="osm_lh:planet_osm_polygon">
    <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
    <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>*E11*</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
    </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:GetFeature>
```

Then I found what I want.

When I use Chinese words to search, it always return Nothing !!

EX: Search "停車場" :

```
    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
    outputFormat="JSON" 
    xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"  
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"  
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"  
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
    http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Query typeName="osm_lh:planet_osm_polygon">
    <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
    <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>*停車場*</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
    </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:GetFeature>
```

Return:
        {"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":0,"features":[]}

I found the GeoServer log message:

```
    Request: getFeature
        service = WFS
        version = 1.1.0
        baseUrl = http://127.0.0.1:8090/geoserver/
        query[0]:
            filter = [ name is like *??????* ]  <==== HERE
            typeName[0] = {osm_lh}planet_osm_polygon
        outputFormat = JSON
        resultType = results
    2014-01-27 13:01:00,232 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

So what happen to this ?? Please help !

Thanks !

Tai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the java code below for test and finally the GeoServer's log displays Chinese words correctly. Please DO NOT use GeoServer's Demo requests web page for test, because the webpage will not send UTF-8 format to WFS service and you will get ??? words.

======== Java test code for WFS request ==============

```
package JVrsAp.demo;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;

public class PostWFSDemo {
    public PostWFSDemo() {
        StringBuffer myWFSRequest = new StringBuffer();
        myWFSRequest.append("<wfs:GetFeature service='WFS' version='1.1.0' outputFormat='JSON' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd' xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml' xmlns:wfs='http://www.opengis.net/wfs' xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc' >");
        myWFSRequest.append("<wfs:Query typeName='osm_lh:planet_osm_polygon'>");
        myWFSRequest.append("<ogc:Filter>");
        myWFSRequest.append("<ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard='*' singleChar='.' escapeChar='!'>");
        myWFSRequest.append("<ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>");
        myWFSRequest.append("<ogc:Literal>*E11自行車*</ogc:Literal>");
        myWFSRequest.append("</ogc:PropertyIsLike>");
        myWFSRequest.append("</ogc:Filter>");
        myWFSRequest.append("</wfs:Query>");
        myWFSRequest.append("</wfs:GetFeature>");

//        PostMethod myPost = new PostMethod("http://10.164.64.240:8090/geoserver/wfs");
        PostMethod myPost = new PostMethod("http://127.0.0.1:8090/geoserver/wfs");
        myPost.setRequestBody(myWFSRequest.toString());
        myPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        HttpClient theClient = new HttpClient();
        try {
            theClient.executeMethod(myPost);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        String responseString = myPost.getResponseBodyAsString();
        System.err.println("getRequestCharSet=" + myPost.getRequestCharSet()); //utf-8
        System.err.println("getResponseCharSet=" + myPost.getResponseCharSet()); //ISO-8859-1
        try {
            String xxx = new String(responseString.getBytes(), "utf-8");
            System.err.println("responseString=" + xxx);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex1) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PostWFSDemo postwfsdemo = new PostWFSDemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this bug number of GeoServer.
The bug status is still open....
The priority is MINOR !!!
Oh! No ~~

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-3326

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
    outputFormat=GML3
```

or

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" 
    outputFormat=GML2
```

---

EDIT

For output in JSON format you need to use:

```
 outputFormat=application/json
```

see [WFS output formats](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html#format-options-as-parameter-in-wfs-requests)

Comment: outputFormat="GML2" ==> response unknow
        outputFormat="GML3" ==> no response, hang there..

Comment: Which character set did  you use into `Settings/Global Settings`?

Comment: character set is UTF-8

Comment: Also, what did your Geoserver log shows when you ask for the chinese word? You can upload the log on dropbox.com and put here only the public link.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/plhldzv0377ydf6/geoserver.log

Comment: I've corrected my response (without quotation marks). Please, try again all the output formats (inclusive jsonp and csv). And please, pay attention to WMS service versions when you use GML.

Comment: <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
outputFormat="application/JSON" 
xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"  
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"  
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"  
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<wfs:Query typeName="osm_lh:planet_osm_polygon">
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
<ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>*E11自行*</ogc:Lit...

Comment: I got the same result ....with outputFormat=application/json

Comment: Dear Sorin Călinică,
I have tried all output format in the link you mentioned.
Only JSON is best format for me.(parser)
I do not think that output format will be the key for this issue. But I am glad to see more reference options. Thanks you! (I use GeoServer's Demo requests for these tests.)